# Spring boot Mongo DB .yml configuration

Tags: java, mysql, mongodb, hibernate, spring-boot

When I use MySQL and hibernate for spring boot, I use below configuration in  .yml file

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost/userName?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull
    username: userName
    password: password
    driverClassName: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

  jpa:
    show-sql: false
    hibernate:
      dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
      format_sql: false
      ddl-auto: update
```

If it is mongoDB instead of MySQL and hibernate how does it change?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The mongodb properties are all prefixed with spring.data.mongodb. For user property you would use

```
spring:
  data:
      mongodb:
        user: test
        password: passwordvalue
        uri: mongodb://host:27017/db
```

The list of available mongodb properties are here:

```
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html
```

You can find them at source for how they are loaded on github:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v2.1.5.RELEASE/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/mongo/MongoProperties.java

Comment: This answer might have been right at the time but it does not work on the current Spring version. At least points to the right documentation. You cannot set both URI and username / password, they are mutually exclusive. Also, `username` and not `user` is the right key.

Comment: As per the mongo db both user name and password are still accepted by mongo in the mongodb uri: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/   In spring they also still accept credentials in the latest version as per documentation: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/application-properties.html#application-properties.data.spring.data.mongodb.uri

Answer (score 3):

You can do as below:

```
spring:
  data:
    mongodb:
      uri: mongodb://yourusername:yourpassword@localhost:27017/yourDB
```

Answer (score 0):

```
spring:
  data:
    mongodb:
      authentication-database: admin
      username: #your_root_user     (default->rootuser)
      password: #your_root_password (default->rootpass)
      database: #your_db_name
      port: #your_port              (default->27017)
      host: #your_host              (default->localhost)
```

For me this worked.

Answer (score 0):

you can put the same link you use to connect in `mongoDbCompass` in the URI property, make sure to let a space after each properties, for me I forgot to add a white space after `uri:` the working yml snippet is as follows:

```yaml
spring:
  data:
    mongodb:
      uri: mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@cluster0.tt44qmp.mongodb.net/test
```

Answer (score 0):

We used:

```
server:
  port: 8090
spring:
  application:
    name: {yourappname}
  data:
    mongodb:
      host: localhost
      port: 27017
      database: coins
      auto-index-creation: true
```